# Where is the getItemReferences Pipeline Used

Tags: publishing, pipelines

I need to disable adding clone references when publishing related items and add logic to do this on an item by item basis based on custom fields that were added. My plan is to replace the processor `Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddItemCloneReferences, Sitecore.Kernel` with a custom one. Is `getItemReferences` used anywhere outside of publishing that would make this approach affect things outside of publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its used only for publishing related items, This pipeline "**getitemreferences**" existed in pre-7.2 versions with only "**AddItemCloneReferences**" and "**AddFileDropAreaMediaReferences**" processors that adds additional items to the publishing queue and was updated on 7.2 to include "**AddItemLinkReferences**" and "**AddItemAliasReferences**" processors .
Even from the Namespace itself it implies that its a Publishing pipeline.

Link: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/latest_technical_reinnovations/posts/related-item-publishing-updated